# I'm getting typescript error while building apk

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Error I got during build  but, it's running fine in browser.**

> typescript error
>           Type BillPage in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/pages/bill/bill.ts is part of the
>           declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/app/app.module.ts
>           and BillPageModule in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/pages/bill/bill.module.ts! Please
>           consider moving BillPage in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/pages/bill/bill.ts to a higher
>           module that imports AppModule in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/app/app.module.ts and
>           BillPageModule in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/pages/bill/bill.module.ts. You can also
>           create a new NgModule that exports and includes BillPage in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM
>           2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/pages/bill/bill.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in C:/Users/GTP
>           SYSTEM 2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/app/app.module.ts and BillPageModule in C:/Users/GTP SYSTEM
>           2/Projects/Ionic/dial2us/src/pages/bill/bill.module.ts.

**My bill.module.ts file is:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BillPage } from './bill';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BillPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(BillPage),
  ],
})
export class BillPageModule {}
```

**app.module.ts** file is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { BillPage } from '../pages/bill/bill';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { RegisterPage } from '../pages/register/register';
import { ForgotPassPage } from '../pages/forgot-pass/forgot-pass';
import { BillDetailsPage } from '../pages/bill-details/bill-details';

import { ComplaintListPage } from '../pages/complaint-list/complaint-list';
import { RegisterComplaintPage } from '../pages/register-complaint/register-complaint';
import { ComplaintDetailsPage } from '../pages/complaint-details/complaint-details';

// import { AuthServiceProvider } from '../providers/auth-service/auth-service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    RegisterPage,
    ForgotPassPage,
    BillPage,
    BillDetailsPage,
    ComplaintListPage,
    RegisterComplaintPage,
    ComplaintDetailsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    LoginPage,
    RegisterPage,
    ForgotPassPage,
    BillPage,
    BillDetailsPage,
    ComplaintListPage,
    RegisterComplaintPage,
    ComplaintDetailsPage

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You need to paste the [mcve] **here** not external linked code

Comment: Sure, I'll edit.

Comment: @SurajRao: Please check

Comment: @SazzadHussain do you import bill page in app.module.ts

Comment: you still need to include app.module.ts in your question..

Comment: @SurajRao: brother I have updated that.

Comment: well.. if you are lazy loading, you dont need to import and include pages in app.module.ts. Remove them

Comment: @AbineshJoyel: Yes

Comment: @SurajRao I am not using Lazy Loading.

Comment: yes you are when you use [IonicPageModule](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicPageModule/) and [IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168725/discussion-between-sazzad-hussain-and-suraj-rao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using `lazy-load`:

- You don't even need `bill.module`, you can delete it completely and it still works
- Then remove all references to the `bill.module.ts` since you deleted that.

**The general case where you get this error is having a `component` declaration in more than one module,**

For that the solution can be `billPages` is already in `app.module` as you also use it in entry components, no need to declare again in `bill.module.ts`

**Your bill.module.ts file becomes:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BillPage } from './bill';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [

  ],
})
export class BillPageModule {}
```

**Since there is no use of it, you can remove it as I said earlier.**

Comment: Actually.. if OP doesnt intend to use lazyloading, there is no need for bill.module.ts at all

Comment: yes then if he doesn't use he can remove it as I mentioned in answer.

Comment: @Sazzad Hussain, edited my answer to cover all the scenarios.

Comment: @Sravan Thanks alot.

Comment: @SazzadHussain, you can accept my answer, if you find it useful/.

Comment: @Sravan: Done :)